# Python Snake game borders with coordinates

Tags: python

I am making a version of the Snake game which has the border as below:

Square in the top left corner overlapping in the middle with a square in the bottom right corner

[image]

I have made it so the snake goes out when it hits the border but I am struggling to make it so the food doesn't go outside the border. I have tried stopping this using this code (This code is in a While true: loop) but it doesn't work:

```
if x < -130 and y < -80:
    x = random.randint(-260,260)
    y = random.randint(-260,225)
else:
    gold.goto(x,y)

if x > 130 and y > 80:
    x = random.randint(-260,260)
    y = random.randint(-260,225)
else:
    gold.goto(x,y)
```

The gold is the food. But it still goes outside the border.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what your code is doing. It hits the first if statement and runs gold.goto() when it doesn't hold even if the second if statement does hold. Then it hits the second if statement and runs gold.goto() when it doesn't hold even if the first if statement does hold. So it's going to run gold.goto() whether you like it or not.

You need something like this:

```
if x < -130 and y < -80 or x > 130 and y > 80:
    x = random.randint(-260,260)
    y = random.randint(-260,225)
else:
    gold.goto(x,y)
```

Comment: @HenryWalker Cool. You should accept the answer if it's working for you...